# The recursive way to find whether there exists a way to sum the array elements to get the target sum, is not working

Tags: python, recursion

I need to find whether you can sum the elements of an array or a list to get a target sum. Need to return a boolean value accordingly.
Here's my code:

```
# problem: can the target sum be obtained from a given array?
def can_sum(target_sum, array):
    # base case if target sum is 0, then yes.
    if target_sum == 0:
        return True
    # if it's -ve then no.
    if target_sum < 0:
        return False
    # subtract array elems from the target sum and call the can_sum()
    for num in array:
        new_node = target_sum - num
        if can_sum(new_node, array) == True:
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(can_sum(7, [1, 2]))  # This outputs True which is not correct.
```

I'm new to recursion, I don't entirely understand everything about it, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this problem recursively (for n elements) means that you try each element in turn, and then repeat to solve the same problem with the remaining (n - 1) elements.

When you are calling `can_sum` recursively, you are already subtracting the current element from the target sum, but you need to also remove the element from the remaining elements.

You will also need to do two more things to make your code work:

1. make a copy of the array (because you cannot iterate over an array and delete elements from it at the same time)
2. test for empty array to properly terminate recursion

Comment: Goddamn it, how did I not see that? Fixed my code like this, I edited my post.

Comment: I rolled back your edit; the question should ask exactly one question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I couldn't do that

Answer (score 3):

Your code passes on the same array to the recursive call; so you are basically testing if the numbers 1 and 2 can be *repeatedly* added to form 7, which is indeed true.

You are not showing your exact requirements, but if the task is to check whether the numbers or a subset of them add up to the target sum, you'll need to create a new array for the recursive call with the current `num` removed.

Comment: >but if the task is to check whether the numbers or a subset of them add up to the target sum. Yes, that is the task. Take a look at my new code, I edited my post, is it correct?

Comment: Don't do that. Revert your edit and ask a new question; though I'm afraid in this case it will be somewhat likely to be closed as off-topic. (Our sister site [codereview.se] might be more appropriate for that.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But the code works now, I just passed a new, sliced array to the recursive call, like this: `array[i+1:]`, ignoring the previous number in the array in the next call.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach the problem is to use [power sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), which are basically every possible combination of subsets. This could make your life easier depending on what you are trying to do.